# It's true that $\text{ker}(M/IM\rightarrow N/IN)=\text{ker}(M\rightarrow N)/IM$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ a map of $R$-modules and $\bar{f}:M/IM\rightarrow N/IN$ the induced map between the quotients. It's true that  $\text{ker}(\bar{f})=\text{ker}(f)/IM$?

Some easy remarks:

1. This is true if the formula $f^{-1}(IN)=\text{ker}(f)+IM$ holds.
2. The above formula is true if $f$ is surjective. (sketch: $f(x)= a_1n_1+...+a_rn_r\in IN$ implies $f(x-a_1m_1...-a_rm_r)=0$ and then $x\in \text{ker}(f)+IM$)
3. The above formula doesn't hold in general (take $\iota:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ and $I=6\mathbb{Z}$)

This question is what I interpret of [$(\ker (f))_{\frak{p}}=\ker (f_{\frak{p}})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235879/ker-f-frakp-ker-f-frakp)

Comment: Your are tensoring with $A/I$, and tensor products are not left exact in general.

Comment: On the other hand, localisations are flat, and tensoring with them is exact, so your last line is informally stating this: the question you are citing is using an incorrect definition of what people usually mean by $M_{\mathfrak p}$.

Comment: So an ideal $I$ such that $A/I$ is not a flat $A$-mod would give rise to a counterexample. Do you have an example of this in mind?

Comment: Any proper ideal of the integers: flat modules over principal ideal domains are torsion-free.

Comment: I think you are right. I also came up with this: If $A/I$ is a flat $A$-mod for every ideal $I$ then A must be absolutely flat (Atiyah-Macdonald exercise 2.26 and 2.27). So in every ring which is not absolutely flat there must be a counterexample (for example every Noetherian ring which is not an Artin ring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments by Pedro Tamaroff.

This is not true in general because $\bar{f}$ is esentially $f\otimes Id:M\otimes R/I\rightarrow N\otimes R/I$. So if the formula were true we must have $f$ inyective $\Rightarrow$ $f\otimes Id$ injective and then $A/I$ is flat.

For a concrete example we can take $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x)=2x$ and $I=2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\ker(\bar{f})=\ker(0)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\neq \ker(f)/2\mathbb{Z}=0$